# Copying over files using powershell seems very inconsistent

Tags: powershell

I am not certain I understand where I am going wrong.

I basically have the same command copying and pasting files for different instances.  I guess I could have built it more object oriented, so I can solve the problem once and apply it for different instances, but this is a freaking script, and I just want to copy over dll's and pdb's...

```
gci -path $FromPath\* -Include *.dll, *pdb | ? {$_.Name -match "example1|example2|example3|example4|example5"} | foreach{ 
    write-host("File being moved: "+ $_.Fullname) Copy-item $_.Fullname -destination $ToPath -force 
            }
```

The above works and sends dll's and pdb's to the correct directory.

```
gci -path $FromPath\* -Include *.dll, *pdb | ? {$_.Name -match "example1|example2|example3|example4"}| foreach{ 
    write-host("File being moved: "+ $_.Fullname) Copy-item $_.Fullname -destination $ToPath -force 
            }
```

That does not.  For whatever reason my pdb's don't go over with my dll's.  I can't understand why it only grabs the dll and not the pdb.  It lists both of them if I write out, why doesn't it move over both of them?

Comment: Just checking to see if these are typos... is `*pdb` actually `*.pdb`, and do you have a `;` before `Copy-item`?

Comment: Are you actually using the exact string `"example1|example2|example3|example4"`? the exact value of the regex is important here, since that's the only difference i see

Comment: Thanks both of you.  It really does take a second set of eyes to review code sometimes.  I must have stared at this thing for hours without noticing it.  But yes, it was the fact that I wasn't using a period before the pdb